# I get error when logging into oracle account such as 'hr' from sql developer

Tags: sql, database, oracle

[image: This is the error message I receive]

> An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
>
> ORA-01109: database not open
> 01109. 00000 -  "database not open"
> *Cause:    A command was attempted that requires the database to be open.
> *Action:   Open the database and try the command again
> Vendor code 1109

Comment: Can you check whether the database is up and running? Is the database you are trying to connect to installed on your desktop, or is it somewhere else in your organisation?

Comment: Also, a common beginner's mistake is to install Oracle SQL Developer and assume it includes a database, which it does not. You will also need a database, if you don't already have one. If you do have one, what connection details are you using (without sharing the password)?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Its already opened but still getting the same error while making connection in Oracle SQL Developer software. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70706962/oracle-db-service-is-already-opened-but-still-getting-database-not-open-error

Answer (score 0):

Please use below syntax to open the database,

```
ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
```

Also you can check if your database is READ ONLY or READ WRITE using,

```
select name, open_mode from v$database;
```

Comment: Its already opened but still getting the same error while making connection in Oracle SQL Developer software. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70706962/oracle-db-service-is-already-opened-but-still-getting-database-not-open-error

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue, there are tow options, each one depends whether the database is in your own laptop or is in a different server.

**Option 1**

If the database is in your own laptop, please open a windows cmd and run:

CMD> sqlplus / as sysdba

```
SQL> ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
```

or

```
SQL> SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE
SQL> STARTUP
```

**Option 2**

If the database is in another server, you would need access to it, either is a Linux or a Windows Server. The process is more or less the same as before for windows, for Linux/Unix is a bit different:

1. You connect by SSH to the server where the database is located with the user who owns the database sofware.
2. You load the environment variables as ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID if they are not loaded by default.
3. Then you run the commands shown above.

By the way, you need the user SYS, you cannot do this with HR, which is basically an example schema.

Comment: Its already opened but still getting the same error while making connection in Oracle SQL Developer software. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70706962/oracle-db-service-is-already-opened-but-still-getting-database-not-open-error